# Powershell logic to execute the same script again

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script like below.

A (do health check)

B ( hereafter B executing I want to execute A again, do I need to write A after B again, or is there any away to call and execute A only and then proceed to C )

C

I hope you got what I am trying to say here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group your code into *functions* - named reusable blocks of code:

```
function A { 
  # health checks
}

function B {
  # whatever B is supposed to do
}

function C {
  # whatever C is supposed to do
}

A     # start by executing A
B     # execute B 
A     # execute A again
C     # execute C
```

For more information, see the [`about_Functions` help file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions)

Comment: That's really helpful to build my logic.
Thanks again..!